# How to create a dojo.mobile.view programatically ?

Tags: dojo

I am now developing an app and i need to create dojo.mobile.view with dynamic ID, i need  a code on how to create a view in dojo view in click event .

Answer (score 1):

This is the code snippet from dojo reference guide which is at http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/mobile/View.html

It provides you the enough information to create view on runtime.

```
var view1 = new View(null, "view1");

var heading1 = new Heading({
  label: "View 1"
});
view1.addChild(heading1);

var categ1 = new RoundRectCategory({
  label: "Documents"
});
view1.addChild(categ1);

var list1 = new RoundRectList();
view1.addChild(list1);

var counter = 4;
for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
  var item1 = new ListItem({
    icon: "images/i-icon-"+i+".png",
    label: "Document 000"+counter,
    moveTo: "view2"
  });
  list1.addChild(item1);
  counter++;
}

view1.startup();
```